# Restart container after another container is deployed

Tags: docker, dokku

I have a project running multiple web apps on a single server using Dokku. Let's imagine web apps/containers are A, B and C, and then I have a container D which is not web app but it's a collection of shared codebase between containers A, B and C (such as DB model definitions, configurations etc.).

Everything works great but the problem is that when container D is updated I need to restart all other containers (A, B and C) so that they can see the changes applied. My first thought was to have a script inside container D which would be executed on `post-deploy` trigger but since this script would be ran inside container it means it can't access host's files.

Since I've started using Dokku just recently I was wondering what would be the easiest way to simply execute this after container D is successfully deployed:

```
dokku ps:restart A
dokku ps:restart B
dokku ps:restart C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "post-deploy" script options. You can mount the docker socket onto D container. That way container D can run restart other containers via:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http:/v1.24/containers/<container-name>/restart
```

---

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction but I still had to dug quite a bit down to understand I also needed to install Docker in my container D.

Comment: You don't need to install docker in the container. By just mounting the docker socket you should be able to run docker commands on the host.

Comment: I don't know if it should but it doesn't work. When I try to run `docker` from within container D (without Docker installed) I get `docker: No such file or directory`. If I try to also mount `/usr/bin/docker` then I get similar error: `/usr/bin/docker: No such file or directory`. Installing Docker inside container D was the only solution.

Comment: Docker has a client server architecture. Docker commands be issued via curl. For example, to restart a container just issue: `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http:/v1.24/containers/<container-name>/restart`.
This command can be issued from inside a container given that `docker.sock` is mounted. There is no need to install docker inside the container and have a larger container.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @yamenk the full answer is:

1. Make sure `curl` is installed in the container D by adding `apk add --no-cache curl` inside `Dockerfile` for container D
2. Add socket to the host's Docker inside container D by mounting storage like this: `dokku storage:mount D /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`
3. Inside `post-deploy` script run the following: `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http:/{version-of-docker-api}/containers/{container-name}/restart`
4. Restart container D

**OLD ANSWER**

To answer my own question with a help of @yamenk using my example containers from the question:

1. Make sure `docker` is installed in the container D by adding `apk add --no-cache docker` inside `Dockerfile` for container D
2. Add socket to the host's Docker inside container D by mounting storage like this: `dokku storage:mount D /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`
3. Restart container D